# How can I invoke an "AktionLink" in an "onClick" event in a "div"?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I use Visual Studio Enterprise 2015. I started a new "ASP.NET Web Application" project and from "ASP.NET 4.6 Templates" I chose "MVC" (MVC4).

In my Index.cshtml View I added the following "divs" in order to create a  navigation menu for my web application:

```
<div class="NavigationItem" onclick="@{Html.ActionLink("HOME", "Index", "home");}">
   HOME
</div>
<div class="NavigationItem" onclick="@{Html.ActionLink("ABOUT", "About", "Home");}">
   ABOUT
</div>
<div class="NavigationItem" onclick="@{Html.ActionLink("CONTACT", "Contact", "Home");}">
   CONTACT
</div>
```

The CSS class "NavigationItem" which I use has the following code:

```
.NavigationItem{
    font-size: 13.5pt;
    color: #3A3A3A;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin: 33px 10px 4px 10px;
}

.NavigationItem:hover {
    color: #CC0000;
    border-bottom: 4px #CDCDCD solid;
}


[![Mouse_Hover][1]][1]
```

The code is executed, but the "onClick" event of the div does not fire when I click on a div. Consequently, the "ActionLink" is never executed. The question is: how can I invoke the execution of the "ActionLink" if the div is clicked?

In case you know how could such think be implemented, or if you have an idea, please let me know. It is going to be a great help to me.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Look at the html your generating to understand why this does not work. What wrong with `<div class="NavigationItem">@Html.ActionLink("HOME", "Index", "home")</div>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thank you very much Stephen Muecke, it does really work. I have to find out a way in order to disable the default colors of the browser with my CSS and then I will have reached my goal. It was one of these times that I get stack and for some reason I cannot see the solution, no matter how obvious it might be...hahaha. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question was given from Stephen Muecke and it is the following:

```
<div class="NavigationItem">@Html.ActionLink("HOME", "Index", "home")</div>
```

@StephenMuecke: Thank you very much for the response :)

In order to keep the behavior of your CSS, you have to add also the following CSS in you CSS file:

```
:link { text-decoration: none; } // Removes this annoying underline from your link.

:visited { color: inherit; }     // Inherits the color behavior which you have applied.
```